# How to convert source to my assets img ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript-generics

I want to change the source.
Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of meal.allergenList" class="btn btn-primary">
    <img [src]="item" alt="">
</div>
```

I want to convert

`if item == 1` I want to convert to src example ../asset/image/1

`if item == 2` I want to convert to src example ../asset/image/2

`meal.allergenList is array [1,2 ...]`

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple try `<img src="../assets/image/{{item}}" alt="Hello">`

Furthur more, you can use Sanitizer to Sanitizing the URL or you can change to the asset path from component ts code. Or you can use a pipe, there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` for this

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
   @Pipe({
      name: 'asset',
      pure: false
   })
    
   export class AssetPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: number): any {  
         if(value== 1){return "../asset/image/1"}
         if(value== 2){return "../asset/image/2"}
         return "";
      }
    }
```

in html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of meal.allergenList" class="btn btn-primary"  >
     <img [src]="item | asset" alt="">
</div>
```